# What forces act ona key in a shaft during the work of spur gears?

Tags: gears, transmission, forces

What forces act on a key in a shaft during the work of spur gears? Are the forces which act on key only from the torque of shaft or also forces from gears mesh and work?

Comment: The key is for location alignment, not force transmission.

Comment: @blacksmith37, that is not correct, and no one cares about the alignment of a motor and a pump impeller